# A person who gets angry when they... vs A person who gets angry when he

Tags: grammar

I don't know why **they** instead of **he** is used in this sentence and is this correct at all?

*A person who gets angry when **they** have to wait is impatient

Answer (score 1):

**They** is used here just to be careful about the gender of the "*person*", as it is not clear whether the person is a male ("he") or female ("she").

Person is a generic word and could be both male or female.
Although, yes, "He" has been used as a default pronoun for all the genders, especially when one is not specific, but the nowadays, with people being extra sensitive about sexism and gender equality, it is preferred not to use a specific masculine pronoun.

Comment: Can't we use "it" in these types of situations?

Comment: No, **it** is used for things, or animals, but never for a human.

Comment: @BellaSwan *It* is often used with babies when somebody doesn't know the gender. (*"Is it a boy or a girl?"*)

Comment: Yes, but that is an exception